# Is weak self needed for table view cell button closure

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uibutton, retain-cycle

In trying to avoid retain cycles, would using `[weak self] in` in a UITableViewCell button action be necessary? Example:

in ViewController's `cellForRow`

```
cell.buttonAction = { (cell) [weak self] in
     self.someFunction()
}
```

in TableViewCell class

```
var buttonAction: ((UITableViewCell) -> Void)?

@IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
     buttonAction?(self)
}
```

Comment: Why don't a look at it in the memory graph debugger, so you can see for yourself? It's a good learning opportunity

Answer (score 4):

The key line to think about is:

```
var buttonAction: ((UITableViewCell) -> Void)?
```

You are offering to *store a function* long-term in an instance property.

Now think about who refers to / owns whom. The view controller owns its view which is-or-owns the table view which owns the cell. Meanwhile the cell owns the function. If the function refers strongly to any of the objects I just mentioned, *that is a retain cycle*. It is a *classic* retain cycle, the absolute model of how retain cycles get made.

---

<sub>[I would like to add a word about how I test for these things. There's a really cheap and easy way: wrap your view controller up in a navigation controller plus a blank root view controller, so that you can *push* your view controller onto it. Implement `deinit` in your view controller. Now run the app, push your view controller, play with it for a bit, and pop it with the Back button. If `deinit` isn't called, you've got a retain cycle.]</sub>

Comment: could you please write with little code how you test vc deollacated from navigation vc when back button tapped ? do you prefer extensions for this kind of tests or write a few line codes as you said. should i ask a new question for my questions or it is okay here  ?

Comment: Hi @matt, just for my knowledge, is it an excellent solution to add a closure in the table view cell?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is necessary to use `unowned` or `weak` to capture `self` in this case.

- Your view controller will most likely have a strong reference to the `UITableView`
- The table view has strong reference to it's `UITableViewCells` and
- Each cell has strong reference to your `buttonAction` closure.

Using self directly will have as an effect a retain cycle.

This is actually pretty easy to test. Try to present the following view controller and dismiss it:

```
class TestTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    var closure: (() -> Void)?
    
    deinit {
        print("TestTableViewCell deinit!")
    }
}

class TestTableViewController: UITableViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        tableView.register(TestTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "TestTableViewCellIdentifier")
    }
    
    deinit {
        print("TestTableViewController deinit!")
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TestTableViewCellIdentifier", for: indexPath) as! TestTableViewCell
        
        cell.closure = { [weak self] in
            guard let self = self else { return }
            self.testFunction()
        }
        
        return cell
    }
    
    func testFunction() {}
}

// Test present
let controller = TestTableViewController()
present(controller, animated: true) {
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
        self.dismiss(animated: true)
    }
}
```

You will have the following output:

> ```
> TestTableViewController deinit!
> TestTableViewCell deinit!
> ```

Now presenting the same view controller without weak and you will see that there is no output, meaning that the `deinit` functions are not get called and the objects stay in the memory.

Answer (score 1):

if you're not using the object of tableviewcell and you only want execute action on the cell make this.

```
var buttonAction: (() -> Void)?

@IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
     buttonAction?()
}
```

and on the cellForRow use this,

```
cell.buttonAction = { [weak self] in
     self?.someFunction()
}
```

for check retain cycles, I usually use this option for check if the memory is retain or not.
[image]